# Por qué en Three js una misma textura luce diferente en las diferentes caras de una geometria?

Tags: javascript, html5, 3d

En three.js la textura de las caras laterales se ve diferente que la misma textura aplicada en las caras superior e inferior para el caso de una simple BoxGeometry ( geometria tipo caja ).

¿ Por qué ocurre y de que forma se puede lograr que las texturas de las 6 caras luzcan similares?

Lo siento, soy nueva en three y se que la pregunta tiene que ver con mi desconocimiento dudo que se trate de un bug o error.

El siguiente es el código de la textura

```
var corkTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/cork-256.png' );

corkTexture.wrapS = corkTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
corkTexture.repeat.set( 10, 10, 10 );
var corkMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: corkTexture } );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 25, .5, 20 );
var Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var layer1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, corkMaterial );
```

En esta url puedes ver el código completo y el resultado:

http://heyplay.org/animation/

Gracias!

Comment: this is the spanish version so please translate yourquestion

Comment: Traduzca el título de la pregunta también. Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: En caso de que no lo hayas intentado, puedes ver [esta repuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39346370/4092887) o buscar `Three.js Cube different textures` en Google. No conozco Three.js, pero puede que te falten mas parámetros para generar el objeto 3d. Saludos.

Comment: Tengo la intención de hacer la pregunta en inglés también (para mejorar el alcance)  Es posible ?

Comment: @NatNite las preguntas en inglés van en https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

Son varias las razones, principalmente el motor de three js es WebGl te recomiendo el siguiente pdf ahí observaras los diagramas y la composición de los elementos WebGl y como se integran estos en el sistema global.
https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2099.1/15478/82457.pdf
Por otra parte el sistema de texturas es independiente al render (En Threejs) y puedes encontrar varios sistemas de texturas:

CanvasTexture

CompressedTexture

CubeTexture

DataTexture

DepthTexture

Texture

VideoTexture

Estos hacia el mismo render webGl, (Lo mismo ocurre con los materiales)
En el caso de blender es el motor de render el que parametrizara las propiedades de las texturas y los materiales:
Cycles
Interno
Juego
y los sistemas de texturas y materiales dependen de este, en este sentido no solo la unificacion de los elementos hacia un modelo es distinto; si no la estructura y la manera en que se renderiza tambien, al igual los sistemas de elementos se ejecutan usando tecnologias diferentes, blender usa binarios de Windows o Unix dependiendo el SO, y adicionales como paquetes de visual basic en Windows y creo que Gtk si no estoy mal en algunos linux; Three js usa open GL tecnologia web.
Saludos y muy buen dia a todos.

Answer (score 0):

El efecto de tu ejemplo sucede debido a los parámetros y coordenadas de textura, para evitar ese efecto puedes modificar las coordenadas de textura para las caras laterales, las coordenadas de textura en webgl van de [0.0, 1.0] sobre los ejes (x/u/s, y/v/t).